# How can I programatically select a sitecore content tree item and expand it?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How can I programatically select a sitecore content tree item and expand it ?

Sitecore version: 6.2
By expanding, I mean expanding the content tree item like in windows explorer ("+").

Comment: Please clarify which version of Sitecore you're using.

Comment: Question is a bit vague... what do you mean by "expand it?"

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I suppose this code will be triggered from somewhere in Content Editor, e.g. by clicking the ribbon button. Then you might need something like this:

```cs
 // it is up to you where to get the item from
 Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, string.Concat(new object[] { "item:load(id=", item.ID.ToString(), ")" }));
 Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, "item:refreshchildren");
```

I can't imagine the scenario when you might need this functionality, but hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

this might be a late reply but you can get all the side menu items via Sitecore API in a repeater or listview control within `<ul>s` and `<li>s` and then use a jQuery plug-in/CSS to [+] or [-] the side menu. I have done this on a site, if you need more information I can send you an example